# what does this pointer do?

Tags: c

```
char* p = "hello world";
```

programmers usually assigns the address of an variable to a pointer. But in the above case, where is the pointer pointing to?

and what in the world is

```
int x =42;
int* p= &x;
int ** r = &p;
```

Comment: No, the * notation does not usually assign the address of a variable to a pointer. It always assigns the address of a block of memory to a "pointer variable". In some cases, the address is that of a piece of data, and in other cases it is the address of a piece of memory that contains the value of a variable. It is easier to understand this aspect of C if you learn a bit about programming in assembler, and debugging machine code execution using a primitive debugger like the DOS debug command.

Comment: What's up with serially psting all your homework questions here?

Comment: "Chris, I mistyped my question on the **r" - did you even read the answer? Names and types of variables do not change the idea of what's going on.

Comment: @Michael Dillon: what about copying your comment to make it an anwser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pointing to an area in the program's read-only memory (usually in the program's machine code itself) containing the ASCII sequence `hello world`. Compare this to:

```
char p[] = "hello world";
```

Which creates an array of 12 `char`s on the stack, which is modifiable just like any other variable, and to:

```
char *p = strdup("hello world");
```

Which creates an array of 12 `char`s on the heap, and sets `p` to be a pointer to this readable *and* writable space of heap memory.

As for your (totally unrelated) second question:

```
int** r = &p;
```

Is simpler than it looks, though it's also bad. `&p` is the *address* of p. So if we did:

```
int x;
int *y = &x;
```

Then the pointer `y` *points to* the variable `x`, so assigning to `*y` changes `x` (and vice versa). We can do this for arbitrarily complex types:

```
int *x;
int **y = &x;
```

Now `y` is still a pointer that points to `x`, but `x` is also a pointer. So in your example, `r` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, and it's value is the address of `p` (a pointer to a `char`). However, it's a bad idea to do this because many platforms have alignment issues with casting from a `char *` type to a larger pointer type.

Comment: I remember reading something about string literal are automatically converted to a temporary global variable. Is this what you're referring to in the first example? Thanks

Comment: String literals are just a sequence of read-only data in your program, just like numeric constants and other such things. `char *p = "string"` is simply pointing the pointer `p` to that section of data.

Comment: Why is creating a pointer to a pointer "bad"?  It is the only way to change what an input to a function points at on the heap.

Comment: @Ed - No, it's a bad idea to create an `int **` pointer and then set it to point to `char **` data without taking alignment into account. It's a little unclear, which is my fault.

Answer (score 3):

The string constant "hello world" must reside somewhere in the application and will be loaded into memory at runtime.  Typically this is in the data section of the executable.  The pointer p points to this address in memory.

The second example simply takes the address of p.  Given that p is on the stack it will be an address into the current stack.

Answer (score 2):

An illustration might be helpful.  Given the following declarations:

```
char *s = "hello world";
int   x = 45;
int  *p = &x;
int **r = &p;
char q[] = "hello world";
```

assume the following memory map (addresses and layout are completely arbitrary and aren't meant to represent any real-world architecture):

```
                 0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03 
    0x00008000:  'h'   'e'   'l'   'l'   
    0x00008004:  'o'   ' '   'w'   'o'
    0x00008008:  'r'   'l'   'd'   0x00  
    ...
s:  0x01000000:  0x00  0x00  0x80  0x00  
x:  0x01000004:  0x00  0x00  0x00  0x2D
p:  0x01000008:  0x01  0x00  0x00  0x04
r:  0x0100000C:  0x01  0x00  0x00  0x08
q:  0x01000010:  'h'   'e'   'l'   'l'
    0x01000014:  'o'   ' '   'w'   'o'
    0x01000018:  'r'   'l'   'd'   0x00
```

The string literal "hello world" is a 12-element array of `char` (`const char` in C++) with static extent, meaning that memory is allocated for it when the program starts and remains allocated until the program terminates.  Exactly where the string literal lives in memory depends on the platform, but it's best to assume that memory is unwritable (i.e., you can't change its contents with `strcpy()` or `strcat()` or `sprintf()`, etc.).  The language standard explicitly states that attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

The line

```
char *s = "hello world";
```

defines `s` as a pointer to char initializes it with the *address* of the literal (0x00008000 in this example).

The line

```
int x = 45;
```

defines `x` as an integer and initializes it with the value 45 (2D in hexadecimal notation).

The line

```
int *p = &x;
```

defines `p` as a pointer to int and initializes it with the address of `x` (0x01000004).

The line

```
int **r = &p;
```

defines `r` as a pointer to a pointer to int and initializes it with the address of `p` (0x01000008).

Note that pointer types are distinct and not always compatible.  Even though `s`, `p`, and `r` all resolve to 32-bit address values in this particular hypothetical, they have different *types* and are not necessarily interchangable, even if they were all set to point to the same location.  Some platforms use different sizes and representations for different pointer types.

And finally, as an added bonus, we have the line

```
char q[] = "hello world";
```

which defines `q` as a 12-element array of char (size taken from the size of the string literal being used to initialize it) and initializes it with the *contents* of the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk sign used when declaring a pointer only means that it is a pointer (it is part of its type compound specifier), and should not be confused with the dereference operator, also an asterisk.

If you want to access the value it returns, you must precede it with a double asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

p points to the first character of a NUL-terminated string. r points to a pointer ... that is to say that it points to a location which holds pointer, to an integer.

Answer (score -1):

p is a memory address stored with `"hello world"`, so the memory p'address has a address position...

`int** r = &p;`

so r is a reference to that address...kinda messed